# Is it possible to get image URLs from the start of a string in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, image, parsing

I have an example string as follows

```
$string = '
http://image.gsfc.nasa.gov/image/image_launch_a5.jpg
http://pierre.chachatelier.fr/programmation/images/mozodojo-original-image.jpg
http://image.gsfc.nasa.gov/image/image_launch_a5.jpg

Alot of text

http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logos/images_logo_lg.gif

more text';
```

I want to be able to extraxt the url's of the first three images (basicly whatever # of images are at the start of the string) but not extract any image URLs once my non image text starts.  I can successfully use regex to grab all the image URL, but it also grabs the last google.com image which is inside the text.

Thanks for any ideas!!

Comment: Try searching. This has been done before. Many times. However, if you can grab all (as purported in the post) then it's merely a small step to 1) stop grabbing after X (alter the approach you already have) or 2) grab N then only "take/use" X (use the approach you already have and merely only use a subset of the result data)

Comment: @pst the N is unknown, the string may have 1 image or 10 images at the start, that is my issue, otherwise i would just grab the first 3 via a simple regex

Comment: See #1 and #2. They don't change. Adapt what you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about avoiding regex and using `explode` instead?

```
$string = '....';

$urls = array();
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL,$string);
foreach ($lines as $line){
  $line = trim($line);

  // ignore empty lines
  if (strlen($line) === 0) continue;

  $pUrl = parse_url($line);

  // non-valid URLs don't count
  if ($pUrl === false) break;

  // also skip URLs that aren't images
  if (stripos($pUrl['path'],'.jpg') !== (strlen($pUrl['path']) - 4)) break;

  // anything left is a valid URL and an image
  // also, because a non-url fails and we skip empty lines, the first line
  // that isn't an image will break the loop, thus stopping the capture
  $urls[] = $line;
}
var_dump($urls);
```

<sup>Example at [IDEOne](http://ideone.com/Zs2kL)</sup>

Comment: Interesting, I really like this idea, I just plugged it in but its grabbing every line right now :(

Comment: @Mark: Sorry about that, try that instead (answer updated). I also took advantage of `parse_url` to validate the image URL.

Answer (score 2):

Let R be regex to grab an image url

You need to grab (R)+  , i.e 0 or more occurrences of R

or mostly ((R)(w)?)+

Where w represents a regular expression to match white spaces.

Comment: Did not spend effort in writing regular expressions, since you already said you can successfully use regex to grab all the image URL :)